# How to unbind events in content script of chrome extension?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Hello I am building a chrome extension. Here is my background script:

```
var toggle = true;
var config = {allPages: []};

chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function(tabId, changeInfo, tab) {
    if (changeInfo.status == 'complete') {
        chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {
             code: 'var config = ' + JSON.stringify(config)
        }, function() {
            chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, { file: "jquery.js" }, function() {
                chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, { file: "content.js" });
            });
        });
    }
 });

chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
    chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {
        code: 'var config = ' + JSON.stringify(config)
    }, function() {
        chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, { file: "jquery.js" }, function() {
            chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, { file: "content.js" });
        });
    });
    toggle = !toggle;
    if(toggle){
        chrome.browserAction.setIcon({path: "on.png"});
        console.log('active ');
    }
    else{
        chrome.browserAction.setIcon({path: "off.png"});
        console.log('not active ');
        }

    });
chrome.runtime.onConnect.addListener(function(port) {
    port.postMessage({toggle: toggle}); 
});
```

Background script injects a content script to a page when it loads (as the extension must be active from the start) and I also switch on/off the extension with a click on an extension icon.

From bakground script I send a message to content script that contains true or false and a function "do" does its job. if it is true - by pressing shift and making click I push the url to the array. Here is my content script (simplified):

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    function do(answer) {
        if (answer) {
            console.log('active');
            var url = document.location.href;
            var page = {
                url: url
            };
            $('body').keydown(function(e) {
                if (e.shiftKey) {
                    document.body.onclick = function() {
                        config.allPages.push(page);
                        chrome.storage.local.set({'config': config}, function ()                   {
                            console.log('savedPage: ', config);
                        });
                    };
                }
            });
    } else {
         console.log('not active');
         $('body').unbind('keydown');              

    }
}

var port = chrome.runtime.connect({name: "knockknock"});
port.onMessage.addListener(function(msg) {
    do(msg.toggle);
    });
});
```

If I click on the extension icon again it is inactive and it sends false to my function "do". So it must do nothing when I press shift and click. But still after i have pressed shift and clicked 1 time even if I deactivate my extension the function "do" works as if I sent it true.

As far as I understand the reason of that is in closures, right? But I really don't know how to get rid of them and to unbind my events when I send false to my "do" function. I tried something like

```
$('body').unbind('keydown');
```

as you can see from my code. Also I tried

```
document.body.onclick = null;
$('body').unbind();
```

but those didn't help. Maybe the question is easy but I really need a fresh eye to look at my code. Or maybe the problem is in my background instead?

Many thanks in advance for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Solution:

`onclick` attribute has nothing to do with your handlers; they are processed internally by jQuery.

`$('body').keydown(f)` [is equivalent to `$('body').on('keydown', f)`](http://api.jquery.com/keydown/) but not `$('body').bind('keydown', f)`.

[`.unbind()`](http://api.jquery.com/unbind/) only works on `.bind()`. For your case, you need to use [`.off()`](http://api.jquery.com/off/):

```
$('body').off('keydown');
```

That said, it won't affect the listener you attached to `document.body.onclick` - you may want to clear that as well.

### Remarks:

In general, that `off()` will remove *all* listeners, which may not be what you want if your script grows more complicated. To be able to switch off a specific listener, it should have a reference to it, for example it should be named:

```
function onKeydown(e) { /*...*/ }
$('body').keydown(onKeydown);
// ...
$('body').off('keydown', onKeydown); // Easier to understand what's happening
```

---

It might be a good idea to also switch your extension off if the port connection breaks (for example, if the extension is restarted or crashes). Add a listener to `port.onDisconnect` to achieve this.

---

It's maybe not a good idea to listen to <kbd>Shift</kbd> in advance only to set another listener. If all you want to know is whether <kbd>Shift</kbd> is pressed when you click the mouse, you can - `e.shiftKey` is defined in the click event.

Unless, of course, you want the second handler to "stick" after pressing <kbd>Shift</kbd> once.

Comment: thank you so much for your answer. I did some simple examples and `off()`worked fine, as well as `.bind()` and `unbind()`. But for my code that's not enough unfortunately (( I tried to make my code simpler and as I can determine my problem is in my background - in toggling. As for `shift` I really need this in my extension as when a user presses it the cursor changes and then the user understands that he/she can click. And as per `port.Disconnect` - thank you for your advice. I guess, I'll make another question about toggling on click in background.

Comment: Yes, maintaining open ports seems like an overkill. You can always just send messages instead.

Comment: is it OK to send messages instead of having the long-lived channel?

Comment: Yes. The worst that can happen is that there will be nobody listening - you should check for that in the callback with `chrome.runtime.lastError` to silence the error.